# Display first n characters of a string by stripping html

Tags: asp.net, string, c#-4.0

I have a long string and I want to display the first 50 characters of it (without including the HTML content). Can anyone suggest any method?

This is the code:

```
eBdb.EpubReader.Epub Epubobj = new eBdb.EpubReader.Epub(myPath);
litepub.Text = Epubobj.GetContentAsHtml();
```

In litepub.Text I am getting text along with HTML. But I want to display only first 50 characters from the result of that function.

Comment: Could you show us what you've done so far? The question isn't clear. What HTML content?

Comment: Try this 
[link][1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038104/parsing-html-to-get-content-using-c-sharp


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038104/parsing-html-to-get-content-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Regex.Replace(source, "<.*?>", string.Empty).Substring(0,49);
```

Comment: You should never parse HTML with regular expressions. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not to see why.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). You could take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785092/c-htmlagilitypack-extract-inner-text) on more information on how to get started.

Comment: But the output that I am getting is in string form. It is not an HTML file.

Comment: @coder311: But from your question, it seems that your string contains HTML no?

Comment: It does contain HTML content in it. But it is form of a string, not a file. Can I use HTML Agility Pack for strings containing HTML?

Comment: @coder311: Yes you can. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535878/can-i-use-html-agility-pack-for-this