# split special text in string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, split

i have this string

```
http://localhost:1209/Pages/ap-aria.aspx text: <p><img alt="" src="http://localhost:1209/ckeditor/plugins/imagebrowser/browser/Hydrangeas.jpg" style="width: 1024px; height: 768px;" />qswdqwdqweqweqe</p>
```

now i want get image tag.how i cant split this string that return just image tag to me ?
i want get this result

```
<img alt="" src="http://localhost:1209/ckeditor/plugins/imagebrowser/browser/Hydrangeas.jpg" style="width: 1024px; height: 768px;" />
```

thank's for your help

Comment: Does the url belong to the string? If you need to parse html use an available library like `HtmlAgilityPack`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex to extract the image tag. You need a non-greedy match, that stops at the first occurrence of the end of the tag (`/>` or `</img>`). See [this link](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%3Cimg.%2B%3F%28%2F%3E%7C%3C%2Fimg%3E%29%29&input=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1209%2FPages%2Fap-aria.aspx%20text%3A%20%3Cp%3E%3Cimg%20alt%3D%22%22%20src%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1209%2Fckeditor%2Fplugins%2Fimagebrowser%2Fbrowser%2FHydrangeas.jpg%22%20style%3D%22width%3A%201024px%3B%20height%3A%20768px%3B%22%20%2F%3Eqswdqwdqweqweqe%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cimg%20%2F%3E%0A%0A%3Cimg%20src%3D%22bla%22%3E%3C%2Fimg%3E%0A) for a demo.

To put this into practice:

```
        string text = "http://localhost:1209/Pages/ap-aria.aspx text: <p><img alt=\"\" src=\"http://localhost:1209/ckeditor/plugins/imagebrowser/browser/Hydrangeas.jpg\" style=\"width: 1024px; height: 768px;\" />qswdqwdqweqweqe</p>";
        Regex regex = new Regex("(<img.+?(/>|</img>))");

        if (regex.IsMatch(text))
        {
            //the text contains an img tag.
            string imgTag = regex.Match(text).Captures[0].Value;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't parse HTMl with regex ([mandatory Regex-HTML link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)). Using an appropriate parser such as the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) should do the trick. You can then combine [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535878/can-i-use-html-agility-pack-for-this) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535878/can-i-use-html-agility-pack-for-this) previous SO posts to do what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to parse html use an available library like [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
string result = null;
var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlText);
var img = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img").FirstOrDefault();
if(img != null)
{
    result = img.OuterHtml;
}
```

Result:

```
<img alt="" src="http://localhost:1209/ckeditor/plugins/imagebrowser/browser/Hydrangeas.jpg" style="width: 1024px; height: 768px;">
```